# mPDF lists not displaying the same as original HTML

Tags: php, nested-lists, mpdf

I have a simple list generated via PHP and MySQL which, when html outputted directly to browser does exactly what it's suppose to.  However; using MPDF 5.7 the sublists do not use the *list-style-type*.  I tried upgrading to MPDF 6.0 however, it does the same thing and even worse puts the content of the `<li>` on a new line.  I have of course included screen shots of all examples I mentioned here.  Any idea why it's doing this and how to fix it so it outputs exactly like the HTML version of the list?

**HTML List**

---

```
<ol class="">
  <li data-id='5' >
    <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_5'><strong>Call To Order/Approval of Agenda</strong></div>
  </li>
  <li data-id='7' >
    <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_7'><strong>Confirmation of Minutes available on Website</strong></div>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-latin">
      <li data-id='25' >
        <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_25'><a href='http://www.carrotriver.ca/uploads/2017%20Council%20Minutes/Minutes%20November%2015%2C%202017.pdf'>November 15, 2017</a></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li data-id='9' >
    <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_9'><strong>Presentation of By-Election Results</strong></div>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-latin">
      <li data-id='11' >
        <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_11'>Deputy Mayor and Committee Appointments as well as cheque signing</div>
      </li>
      <li data-id='10' >
        <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_10'>Oath of Office, Public Disclosure Statement, Statement of Commitment to the Code of Conduct</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li data-id='12' >
    <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_12'><strong>Delegations:</strong></div>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-latin">
      <li data-id='13' >
        <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_13'>None</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li data-id='14' >
    <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_14'><strong>Correspondence for Consideration:</strong></div>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-latin">
      <li data-id='27' >
        <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_27'><a href="http://council.carrotriver.ca/uploads/5 a Woodland Caribou Letter.pdf">Ministry of Environment – Woodland Caribou Range Planning Process</a></div>
      </li>
      <li data-id='26' >
        <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_26'><a href="http://council.carrotriver.ca/uploads/5 b KCRA Rodeo Letter to the RM of Moose Range.pdf">RM of Moose Range – KCRA Rodeo Sponsorship</a></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li data-id='17' >
    <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_17'><strong>Correspondence for Information only:</strong></div>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-latin">
      <li data-id='21' >
        <div class='dd-handle'  id='list_21'><a href="http://council.carrotriver.ca/uploads/5 b KCRA Rodeo Letter to the RM of Moose Range.pdf">Pasquia Regional Park - Allocation Request</a></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**HTML Output (Expected Result)**

---

[image: HTML Output]
**MPDF 5.7**

---

[image: MPDF 5.7]
**MPDF 6.0**

---

[image: MPDF 6.0]

Comment: I have figured out the newline problem.  Turns out my list was adding divs to the li content which in turn made mPDF extend the div 100% and put the text on a new line.  Removing the divs placed all of the text back beside the numbers, however the list-style-type still doesn't work.

Comment: Looking at the mPDF documentation, <li> and <ol> are "recognised and supported (to some extent)", and looking at the HTML output and mPDF 5.7 output, they are the same except for some design differences (e.g. "a" in html, "1" in mPDF 5.7). mPDF accepts some CSS, but I am not sure, if you can change the symbols used for lists, especially since you use the same tag for lists and sublists, which mPDF obviously resolves with the same symbol (i.e. digits instead of letters).

Comment: Wrote this as an answer by mistake at first.

Comment: So, there are examples, which give the same output as your html example?

Comment: No... the examples actually work.  My lists do not.  They're constructed pretty much the same (no hard to construct a list).

Comment: So, if they are pretty much the same and the examples work, but your code doesn't, then find the differences and figure out which difference leads to your code not working.

Comment: Okay; played around a bunch more and figured out being I had the list inside a table this affected the list-types.  I have no reasoning as to why it did but once I ended the table before the list, it labeled the items as they should.

Comment: Good, that you were able to find the problem.